Evaluating the integral $I= \int^{1}_{-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}(1+\alpha x^2)} dx$ using complex analysis
I am trying to evaluate the integral:
$$
I =
\int^{1}_{-1}\frac{1}{\,\sqrt{\,{1 - x^{2}}\,}\,\left(1 + \alpha x^{2}\right)}{\rm d}x
$$
using complex analysis.

To handle the square root $\sqrt{1 - z^2}$, I place a branch cut for $\sqrt{z}$ along the negative real axis.
The contour for this setup consists of:

A line segment from $-1$ to $1$ along the real axis.
Small semicircles around $z = -1$ and $z = 1$ to avoid singularities, which I believe contribute zero to the integral.
Line segments from $-\infty$ to $-1$ and from $1$ to $\infty$.
A large semicircle extending to infinity, which I also believe contributes zero to the integral due to the behavior of the integrand at infinity.

This can be done using a similar reasoning as for the small
semicircle.





This gives the following image:


Given this setup, I am unsure how to handle the contributions from the line segments $(-\infty, -1)$ and $(1, \infty)$: Should I evaluate them separately, or can they be related to the original integral on $\left[-1, 1\right]$ ?.
I attempted to use the branch cut of $\sqrt{z}$ should be used here, but I tried this and gave no satisfying results.

For now, I just stated the following:
$\oint_{C}{\frac{dz}{\sqrt{1-z^2}(1+\alpha z^2)}} = I_{[-1,1]} + I_{[-\infty,-1]} + I_{[1,\infty]} = 2\pi i \,Res(f,z = \frac{i}{\sqrt{\alpha}})$
Any guidance or hints on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated!

This integral can easily be evaluated without complex analysis by letting $\theta=\sin^{-1}x$, then substituting $\tan\theta=t$.

Integrals on finite intervals can be evaluated by contour integration, but the usual strategy involves dogbones, not semicircles.

@MathGuy, thank you for your suggestion. I was aware of alternatives. However, I wanted to do it using complex analysis.

@J.G. Thank you for your suggestion. I think this might work. Thank you all! I will let you know something later.

$\tt Mathematica$ yields a quite long result with several $\color{red}{\tt sqrt}$ and some $\color{red}{\tt arctan}$.

Hint: Substitute $x=\dfrac y{\sqrt{1+y^2}}\iff y=\dfrac x{\sqrt{1-x^2}}$. The subsequent integral is much simpler using residue calculus; no need to consider residues at infinity.
$$\int_{-1}^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}\left(1+\alpha x^2\right)} = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{dy}{1+(1+\alpha)y^2}$$
